# How can I count distinct columns inside a group?

Tags: mysql, aggregate, pivot, count

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, surname, id_number, gender FROM table1;
```

How do I filter by gender to get the gender breakdown of the results of the above query? Do I use a subquery? If so, how do I write the subquery?

**Note in my table there are duplicate entries for `id_number`**

Sample Data:

```
-------------------------------------
Name    | Surname   |ID_No   |Gender|
-------------------------------------
John       Doe        1234A6    M
Jane       Doe        2553B7    F
Steve      Jobs       2636A8    M
```

Expected Output

```
--------------
  M   |   F  |
---------------
  2       1
```

Comment: Is `id_number` not already unique? Do you have duplicate `id_number`s in the table?

Comment: @EvanCarroll, yes I have duplicate `id_numbers` in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id_number` is **not** `UNIQUE` (by extension) nor a `PRIMARY KEY` what you want is [`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

```
SELECT
    gender, count(DISTINCT name, surname, id_number)
FROM table1
GROUP BY gender;
```

And you want either,

- an index on `gender`, and a second index on `name, surname, id_number`
- an index on `gender, name, surname, id_number`

No guarantee that MySQL will do something smart with them anyway, but it'll use them for the first sorting into Male/Female which will at the least reduce the `DISTINCT` load by ~1/2. As compare to the current answer which may double it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this will work for you.  I don't have a MySQL instance available to me to check my syntax, but this should get you close.

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(id_number)
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT
            name
            , surname
            , id_number
            , gender
        FROM table1
        ) AS D
GROUP BY gender;
```